# Elasticsearch: Query to search if field not exists at all, should not match [ ] (empty array field)

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some documents with field `links : []` while other documents don't have the field `links` at all.

I want to get documents which don't have the field `links` at all.
I have tried the following query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "links"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this query also returns the documents with `links:[]`

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to modify mapping of field to consider null values , refer to this link ( [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/null-value.html) ) .

You could use a wildcard query * inside boolean to see if it got any terms - but thats a very inefficient / slow way to query and may not be practical depending on cardinality of that field.